# Why can't I import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH from docx.enum.text?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, python-docx

I transferred some code from IDLE 3.5 (64 bits) to pycharm (Python 2.7). Most of the code is still working, for example I can import WD_LINE_SPACING from docx.enum.text, but for some reason I can't import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.

At first, nearly non of the imports worked, but after I did
pip install python-docx
instead of
pip install docx
most of the imports worked except for WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.

```
# works
from __future__ import print_function
import xlrd
import xlwt
import os
import subprocess
from calendar import monthrange
import datetime
from docx import Document
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from docx.enum.text import WD_LINE_SPACING
from docx.shared import Pt

# does not work
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
```

I don't get any error messages but Pycharm marks the line as error: 
"Cannot find reference 'WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH' in 'text.py'".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```py
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
```

and then substitute `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT` wherever `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH` would have appeared before.

The reason this is happening is that the actual enum object is named `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT`, and a decorator is applied that also allows it to be referenced as  `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH` (which is a little shorter, and possibly clearer). I expect the syntax checker in PyCharm is operating on direct module attributes and doesn't pick up the alias, which is resolved by the Python parser/compiler.

Interestingly, I expect your code would work fine either way. But to get rid of the annoying message you can use the base name.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses pylint it can be easily suppressed with `# pylint: disable=E0611` added at the end of the import line.

Comment: Is there any suggestion in the question that pylint is somehow involved in this problem?

Comment: No, but this information could help me and (in my opinion) many others if they somehow (just like me) found this question in Google. And the OP got the wanted answer a long time ago. Is this thinking wrong? Because I'm not pretty confident about it.

Comment: Answers should relate to the questions that they're posted on. In this case, the question was about an import, but your answer is about suppressing pylint. I couldn't see any connection between the question and your answer. If you feel there is a clear link, it would be better if you could [edit] your answer and explain why this answer might help someone with the same problem. If there isn't a link, you could write a new question and answer it yourself.